# How to fix : "NPM start broken while using SASS instead of CSS in my Angular 7 Project"

Tags: angular, npm, sass

I set angular project through angular/cli with following versions

> Angular CLI: 7.3.1
>       Node: 10.15.1
>       OS: darwin x64 / MacOS Mojave
>       Angular: 7.2.4
>       NPM: 6.4.1

```
but after setup while using npm start, its broken and showing error 



ERROR in ./src/styles.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/styles.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.sassLoader  (/Users/yogesh/Desktop/NG/rox/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js:46:72)
```

Comment: Just do `npm install node-sass` and then `npm start`..! All done :)

Comment: @RohitSharma, Already tried before asking the question, but tried again still not working

Comment: its fixed , I uninstall node from system by deleting it from several folders like

/usr/local/lib 
/usr/local/include
/usr/local/bin

manually , every folder node or node_modules.. just deleted them after that, I install fresh copy of node and everything work smoothly...... cheers!!!!